# Javascript - Promise pending

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm learning work with promises and i want to select data from a table and add this to an array and send this array to next then.

I do this but it return `[Promise {<pending>}]`:

```
    var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var stamp = req.params.stamp;
      var part = [];
      part.push(request.query("SELECT u_order, u_familia, u_part, u_type FROM u_part (nolock) where u_order <'92' and u_order <> '100'"));
      resolve(part);
      // or
      // reject ("Error!");
    });

    p1.then(function(value){
      console.log(value);
    }, function(reason){
      console.log(reason);
    });
```

I think that i have to wait for promise but how?

**UPDATE**

Now i want to iterate the array part and do a select to another array.
After that i have to create a new array with this stucture:

```
-PARTS
      - part
            - u_order
            - u_familia
            - u_part
            - u_type
            - articles (article from each part)
```

And i try this but cannot access to array articles

```
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var stamp = req.params.stamp;
      request.query("SELECT u_order, u_familia, u_part, u_type FROM u_part (nolock) where u_order <'92' and u_order <> '100'").then((data)=>resolve(data));
      // or
      // reject ("Error!");
    });



    p1.then(function(value){
      var stamp = req.params.stamp;
      console.log(value.length);
      for(var i= 0; i<value.length; i++)
      {
        console.log(value[i]);
        request.query("SELECT st.u_posic, sc.ref, sc.qtt, sc.design FROM st INNER JOIN sc ON st.ref = sc.ref where sc.ststamp ='"+stamp+"' and st.u_posic = '"+value[i].u_order+"'").then((data)=>resolve(data));
      }

    }, function(reason){
      console.log(reason);
    });

    p1.then(function(part, articles){
      var parts = [];
      console.log("PART: " +part.length);
      for(var j= 0; j<part.length; j++)
      {
        console.log(part[j].u_order);
        console.log(part[j].u_familia);
        console.log(part[j].u_part);
        console.log(part[j].u_type);
        console.log(articles[j]);
      };
    });
```

Thank you

Comment: does `request.query` return a promise?

Comment: `I think that i have to wait for promise but how?` you are waiting for the promise, the problem is you are not waiting for request.query to finish, you just resolve an array of whatever the heck request.query call returns

Comment: Basically `request.query` is an async function returning the promise. Change this:

`part.push(request.query("some-query")` 

to

`request.query("some-query").then((data)=>resolve(data)`

Comment: Ok, i understand that. So how can i do this without request.query?

Comment: You can also Use Promise.all like this:

`Promise.all(part,(data)=>resolve(data))`. Keep in mind that data will be an array.

Comment: @ApoorvJoshi - or, avoid the Promise constructor anti-pattern altogether and simply `var p1 = request.query("SELECT u_order, u_familia, u_part, u_type FROM u_part (nolock) where u_order <'92' and u_order <> '100'");
` - I'm assuming that `request.query` returns a promise as you state - looking at your other comments though ...

Comment: @ApoorvJoshi - `Promise.all(part,(data)=>resolve(data))` WHAT is that!!!???

Comment: @JaromandaX I think the OP's requirement was to store it in the array. So, for array of promises I used `promise.all`.

Comment: yes, but that code is completely misrepresentative of how to use `Promise.all`

Comment: I implement your sugestions and works fine but now i need to create another promise to iterate the array part and create a new array articles. But when i resolve articles the .then doesn't recognize this array. @ApoorvJoshi

Comment: I will need a code snippet to understand what you mean.

Comment: I update the questions. What i'm doing wrong? How can get the two arrays in same promise? @ApoorvJoshi

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
var stamp = req.params.stamp;
var p1 = request.query("SELECT u_order, u_familia, u_part, u_type FROM u_part (nolock) where u_order <'92' and u_order <> '100'");

p1.then((value) => {
    console.log(value.length);
    var promise_arr = [];
    for(var i= 0; i<value.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(value[i]);
        promise_arr.push(request.query("SELECT st.u_posic, sc.ref, sc.qtt, sc.design FROM st INNER JOIN sc ON st.ref = sc.ref where sc.ststamp ='"+stamp+"' and st.u_posic = '"+value[i].u_order+"'"));
    }
    //Since request.query returns a promise we need to resolve all of the promises using Promise.all
    return Promise.all(promise_arr);
}, (reason) => {
    console.log(reason);
}).then((part) => { //This is where you receive result form Promise.all
    var parts = [];
    console.log("PART: " +part.length);
    for(var j= 0; j<part.length; j++)
    {
        console.log(part[j].u_order);
        console.log(part[j].u_familia);
        console.log(part[j].u_part);
        console.log(part[j].u_type);
        console.log(articles[j]);
    };
})
```